# Supabase with JWT auth from Python client doesn't work with RLS

Tags: python, next.js, jwt, supabase, supabase-py

I have a problem with Supabase that is related to RLS.

In my Python backend, I set up the supabase client and get the user based on the JWT `jwt` passed by the frontend:

```py
user = supabase.auth.get_user(jwt)
user_id = user.dict().get("user").get("id")

response = (
    supabase
    .table("users")
    .update({"credits": 10})
    .eq("user_id", user_id)
    .execute()
)
```

Without RLS, this works fine, updating the row successfully.

However, with the following RLS rules, nothing is modified and 0 rows are returned:

```sql
create policy "Everybody can select users."
    on users for select
    using ( true );

create policy "Users can update own user."
    on users for update
    using ( auth.uid() = user_id );
```

What am I doing wrong? Obviously I have to use *some* RLS rule… But I guess the authentication check `( auth.uid() = user_id )` doesn't match up when using the JWT.

**I think I need to pass the JWT to the `supabase` client as well, so it's included in all requests, but I don't know how!**

Help!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it like this:

```
# Update this with the data of a currently logged in user
access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..."
refresh_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

supabase: Client = create_client(
    os.environ.get("NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL"),
    os.environ.get("NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY"),
)
supabase.auth.set_session(access_token=access_token, refresh_token=refresh_token)
```

However, I now suggest just using the supabase service role key on the backend:

```py
supabase: Client = create_client(
    os.environ.get("NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL"),
    os.environ.get("SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY"),
)
```

You can then still verify that your user is logged in by running:

```py
supabase.auth.get_user(access_token)
```

Which will make a request to supabase and return the user data.